# c# XPath Navigator Select statement fails due to misinterpretation of token

Tags: xpathnavigator

When attempting to return the value associated with any of the “Qx_x” when the http:// address is loaded to Q91_1, the Navigator fails as it interprets the “Id” in “ProjectId” as a valid token - even though the intent is to only pickup "f id=" .  Is there a way to alter the expression created to prevent the Navigator from not functioning correctly?

```
public string GetResponsesValue(string fieldHeading) {
// Use XPath to get the response value.
string expr = string.Format("/Fields/f[@id=\"{0}\"]", fieldHeading);
XPathNodeIterator xpni = Navigator.Select(expr);
return xpni.MoveNext() ? xpni.Current.Value : null;
}

// Cached XPathNavigator
private XPathNavigator xpn;
private XPathNavigator Navigator {
get {
if (xpn == null) {
    XPathDocument xpd = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(SurveyResponses));
    xpn = xpd.CreateNavigator();
    }
return xpn;
}
}
```

The data in “SurveyResponses” referenced above in StringReader is represented below.

DataResponse XML structure appears as follows (start end arrows removed to allow entry here
Fields
  f id="Q21_1">30121 /f
  f id="Q91_1">http://xxx.yyy.net/run.aspx?GroupId=188&ProjectId=1096&RecordId=634 /f
  f id="Q48_3">22101 /f
/Fields

The code works fine as long as the string containing the URL isn't included in the XML.